# NuSOAP with optional parameters

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I am writing my first NuSOAP webservice and got a problem with optional parameters.
Currently the function is registered like this:

```
$server->register(
    'auth',
    array('username' => 'xsd:string', 
            'password' => 'xsd:string',
            'senderid' => 'xsd:string',
            'timestamp' => 'xsd:string',
            'hash' => 'xsd:string'),
    array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
    'encoded'
);
```

How to register parameter senderid as optional? If user pass null, I will get apache warning like variable 3 is missing. There is no option in variable array as I see, because I can pass only key-value parameters.
It disappears if I pass empty string - "", but happens with null value. Googled a lot without answer :(.

Thank you for your help in advance!